# Filter with shopify find()-function

Tags: django, shopify

I'm trying to filter my orders by a specific product_id like this:

```
def export_csv(request, id):
    with request.user.session:
        all_orders = shopify.Order.find(line_items.product_id = id)
```

This however gives me an error ('keyword can't be an expression').

Every Order has an attribute 'line_items' which contains a dictionary, where product_id is a key. How do I filter by this?

And do anyone know, where I can get information about the shopify find()-function?

Answer (score 0):

This is not `shopify` related problem, it's just syntax error. You can't pass anywhere in python some expression as parameter name. if you wan't to do lookup on related field, django does allow it using double underscore syntax. Try this:

```
def export_csv(request, id):
    with request.user.session:
        all_orders = shopify.Order.find(line_items__product_id = id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't work... I tried it already but it doesn't give me any results. I have worked around it with some for-loops, but that seems like a sucky solution.